# How to use event listener on chrome dev tool for page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a javascript application that for some reason upon page load scrolls a few pixels down.

To me it seems like some event gets triggered which is why the page gets scrolled down.

How can I use chrome dev tools to figure out which event is getting triggered on the page load? I have selected 'DomContentLoaded' in Event Listener Breakpoints but that is not providing any valuable information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page you have loaded, then go into Chrome Dev tools and open up the 'Sources' tab. Once you're there make sure the Watch variables/Breakpoints panel is visible by using the button at the top right. Finally look at the list of 'Event Listener Breakpoints that might be setup, or try your own to gather the information you need.

[image: Chrome Dev Tool Event Listener Breakpoints]